# Weird render glitch in rendered video

Tags: rendering, artifacts

I was rendering a scene with a couple of objects in it:

- One object with a shader to act as a "green star"
- Another object surrounding the first object, with a cell fracture in the mix; Usual shader is used.

Upon rendering, the first 390 / 400 frames go well, but on the last few frames, an *odd* artifact appears on about the last few frames of the render.

### Frame in question:

[image: Image with a white "Diamond", mixed with some white noise, on top of the final render]

---

Any additional information can be provided, within reason.

If there is no way to fix the current situation, please let me know.

---

Here is the .blend file if you want to try it out:

[image]

Comment: Also close blender completely and reopen the file to see if it's still there. First try to locate the source of the light(From what I see it's probably a light) tone it down.

Comment: I checked the .blend file and as far as I can see, there should not be anything with that much light, since there is only one light source in the scene.

Comment: Cannot think of anything to suggest except posting the file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Feel free to cut down the contents to only show the issue.